# jquery-UI only one item is draggable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

In my Rails app, after users choose a series of "plant" objects, the images for those plants are displayed and need to be "draggable." The problem is only the first plant that shows up is ever draggable, whether I try to use some Ruby or a div id. I have no idea what's going wrong, and even the resulting HTML page source looks like it should be working. I've found a similar Q&A here: [jQuery Draggable only allowing 1 image to be draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203519/jquery-draggable-only-allowing-1-image-to-be-draggable), but the solution didn't work for my code.

In my application.js:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

In my view, this only makes the first image displayed "draggable":

```
<% @plants.each do |plant| %>  
  <li>                         
 <%= image_tag(plant.image_path, :id => "draggable", :size => "50x50")%>       
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And the same thing using a div or an li id:

```
<% @plants.each do |plant| %>  
  <li id="draggable">                         
     <%= image_tag(plant.image_path, :size => "50x50")%>       
  </li>
<% end %>
```

The HTML page source indicates that each item has an id of draggable, but still, only the first item is indeed draggable. I first thought draggable wasn't compatible with the Rails "each" function, but it turns out I can't make ANY other images in my view draggable besides that first plant object. Please help me out. I don't know if it's a bug or a problem with my javascript, I'm fairly new to Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id's should be unique per page (and so it's only taking the first item), try to give the elements a class draggable.

Comment: I now see it's about the same answer as the question you're referring to, but now I wonder what exactly you tried when trying that solution.

Comment: Ah, got it. I went back to the original Q&A and realized I never added the CSS. Thanks, Johan.